# too many arguments for this formula

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am making excel sheet but excel is not allowing me further checks and giving an error `to many argument for this formula`.

kindly give me solution.

`=IF(E2="NL",N2-(J2*0.08),IF(AND(E2="PA",H2="Trip Travel"),(N2*0.01)+N2,(N2*0.02)+N2,IF(AND(E2="PK",H2="Trip Travel"),(J2*0.01)+N2,(J2*0.02)+N2)))`

---

Edit to clarify possible scenarios:

```
 1. E is "NL" and H is "Other"       : return N2+(J2*0.08)
 2. E is "NL" and H is "Trip Travel" : return N2+(J2*0.08)
 3. E is "PK" and H is "Other"       : return N2+(J2*0.01)
 4. E is "PK" and H is "Trip Travel" : return N2+(J2*0.01)
 5. E is "PA" and H is "Other"       : return N2+(N2*0.02)
 6. E is "PA" and H is "Trip Travel" : return N2+(N2*0.01)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the 2nd `IF` function, which has 4 arguments given. `IF` only takes 3:

1. The condition to test
2. The result if the condition is true
3. The result if the condition is false

The problematic section is:

> IF(AND(E2="PA",H2="Trip Travel"), (N2*0.01)+N2, (N2*0.02)+N2, IF(AND(E2="PK",H2="Trip Travel"),(J2*0.01)+N2,(J2*0.02)+N2))

Notice how there are 4 arguments for the `IF` function in that section:

1. The condition: `AND(E2="PA",H2="Trip Travel")`
2. The result if true: `(N2*0.01)+N2`
3. The result if false: `(N2*0.02)+N2`
4. And then this extra argument: `IF(AND(E2="PK",H2="Trip Travel"),(J2*0.01)+N2,(J2*0.02)+N2)`

I'm not sure how exactly to correct this since I can't determine the logic you want from that formula.  However, I'm guessing that either `(N2*0.01)+N2` or `(N2*0.02)+N2` belongs in a different section.

Also, just to help simplify the formula, the "+N2" could be put before the second `IF` and remove all the "+N2"s since all outcomes have N2 added to them. Something like the following (which still has the 4 arguments since I'm not sure how you want the logic corrected):

> =IF(E2="NL",N2-(J2*0.08), **N2**+IF(AND(E2="PA",H2="Trip Travel"),(N2*0.01),(N2*0.02),IF(AND(E2="PK",H2="Trip Travel"),(J2*0.01),(J2*0.02))))

---

Edit the edited question:

This formula should cover the six possibilities in your spreadsheet:

> =IFERROR(N2+IF(E2="NL",J2*0.08,IF(E2="PK",J2*0.01,IF(E2="PA",IF(H2="Trip Travel",N2*0.01,IF(H2="Other",N2*0.02,"n/a")),"n/a"))),"n/a")

Comment: actually i want to make mulitple check in a single cell. like i write. IF(E2="NL",N2-(J2*0.08)this is ist check   IF(AND(E2="PA",H2="Trip Travel") this is second check  ,IF(AND(E2="PK",H2="Trip Travel"),(J2*0.01),(J2*0.02) and that is 3rd one. and all have difrent outcomes. so tell me better solution for this

Comment: @ZeeshanShahid You can make multiple checks, it's just that the syntax wasn't right for the `IF` function. I'm not sure I understand your 3 checks exactly. Could you edit your question to have the full goal? Maybe with an example of the 3 situations your checking for? I'd be glad to help get the formula right, I just don't fully understand the desired outcome at the moment.

Comment: In E column there three choices NL, Pk And PA and in H column there are two choices other and trip travel. and J column have actual amount. We have to calculate amount after commission adding and subtracting. IF(E2="NL",N2+(J2*0.08) it"s mean if E is NL then simple add 8% in actual amount.IF(AND(E2="PK",H2="Trip Travel"),(J2*0.01)+N2,(J2*0.02)+N2. If I select pk from E column trip travel from H column then 1% add in actual amount. IF(AND(E2="PA",H2="Trip Travel")(N2*0.01)+N2, (N2*0.02)+N2, when I select PA from E and trip travel from H then  add 1% like this formula. Calculation formula corect

Comment: @ZeeshanShahid I've edited your question to show the 6 possible combinations of [NL, PK, PA] and [Trip Travel, Other]. I filled in what I thought I have right, but there are some unaccounted for combinations. If you could edit the question further to clarify that would be great

Comment: 1. E is "NL" and H is "Other"       : return N2+(J2*0.08)
 2. E is "NL" and H is "Trip Travel" : return N2+(J2*0.08)
 3. E is "PK" and H is "Other"       : return (J2*0.02)+N2
 4. E is "PK" and H is "Trip Travel" : return,(J2*0.01)+N2
 5. E is "PA" and H is "Other"       : return N2+(N2*0.01)
 6. E is "PA" and H is "Trip Travel" : return N2+(N2*0.01)

Comment: @ZeeshanShahid Thanks- I've edited the answer to include a formula for your scenario

Comment: @ZeeshanShahid If this answered your question, then if you don't mind upvoting/accepting it that would be appreciated. Perhaps see here for more info about StackOverflow: stackoverflow.com/tour